# How to explain this output of a C program

Tags: c

Code:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int a = 0xfffffff7;
    char *b = (char *)&a;
    printf("%08x",*b);
}
```

the output is: `fffffff7`. 
My machine is little-endian. Of course I know `*b` equals `0xf7`, but I don't know why the output of `printf()` is like this.

Comment: what were you expecting?

Comment: `%08x` is asking for hex, 8 characters wide, with leading zeros.  And when printing a char as an integer type it is widened to an int before printing.

Comment: why the output isn't 000000f7

Comment: `char`, on your system, is defined as signed, so the sign bit gets extended when it is widened.

Comment: This is undefined behavior. You're passing a single `char` (which gets promoted to `int` to the `printf()` function, and telling `printf()` that what you passed is a pointer of some sort. It's entirely plausible that this might crash on a platform where pointers are larger than integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your system is small-endian, `a` is stored in memory as `F7 FF FF FF`.

`b` points to the first byte of `a`. (F7)

`*b` evaluates to a `char`. (F7)

`*b` is promoted to an `int` in order to pass it as a parameter, since it's of type `char` (which usually defaults to `signed char`) it is sign-extended to become `FFFFFFF7`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 +-----------------------+
 |  F7   <--b=(char *) &a|
 |  FF                   |
 |  FF                   |
 |  FF                   |
 |                       |
 +-----------------------+


 printf("%08x",*b);
```

//means :

1. `*b` asking the value b  pointer to  (F7)
2. `%08x` is asking for hex,  when printing a char as an integer type it is *widened to an int* before printing. (FFFFFF7 now)

Comment: @TGO Sorry for this stuip mistake .

Comment: Important is that you sorted it out :)